References on when to choose Bayesian vs. frequentist analysis
I'm looking for references discussing and comparing the advantages and drawbacks of Bayesian vs. frequentist analysis in various contexts.
If it makes sense, I'd be particularly interested in learning how people determine this kind of thing at the design stage of a study (for example, I'd be interested in references, if any, that discuss if there are practical constraints on the design of a study that could possibly rule out Bayesian or frequentist methods in the planned analysis). However, I'm not interested only in references discussing the issue from a study design perspective, so this would just be a nice addition and I'd be very glad to get references that discuss other aspects.
I understand that my request is quite broad and that there are probably different approaches and certainly disagreement among practitioners, but my question is out of curiosity, and not to solve a particular problem I would be currently facing. That's why I ask about references, to get a better understanding of the existing arguments. Thanks.

This mostly comes down to preference, what you are familiar with.

It is not as simple as reading some references. You have to immerse yourself in a scientific problem (say thesis), and sharpen your scientific critical thinking. Talk to different experts - yes face-to-face, not on zoom. And see what approach best resonates with YOU - it is a personal choice. In 1988, I started attending the MaxEnt workshops. This year I'll present a tutorial at MaxEnt 2024 in Ghent (Belgium). You are most welcome.

@user2974951 Does it mean I'm unlikely to find good references on this subject then? (as it also seems that people deal with that on a case-by-case basis, as suggested by the other comment) . Maybe I should simply delete my question if it's the case, I don't want to waste other people's time. One thing that prompted my question is that I've seen people defining themselves as "agnostic" relative to Bayesian vs. frequentist methods.

I think you will find a lot of people on either side of the pole defending their position and suggesting that their way is the "right way". But in reality a lot of situations will be far from those ideal/academic/theoretical examples that you will find from such people, and in those cases you will usually be forced to use whatever is available, rather than what is "right".

Thanks for the feedback. I realize now that I can't delete my question. If a moderator wants to do it for me, I see no problem with it.

@Coris: As there are useful comments, we prefer to keep the question for reference!
